# Are orient-DB java hooks capable of providing notifications when a record gets modifed from any client

Tags: java, graph, hook, graph-databases, orientdb

I have just started using OrientDB and one of the most useful features for my project was the hook.
Let me try to explain my setup:

1. OrientDB "Graph" database server running on machine-1, to which many
   clients are connected
2. On Machine-2 i am running a OrientDB Java based client application
3. There are many web applications which are connecting to the OrientDB server for graph database manipulation
4. On Machine-2 java client, i have registered hooks to listen to change
   of certain class records
   I was expecting that whenever a record (of specified class mentioned by hook) is modified the hook will imitate the trigger on java client running on Machine-2
   But in reality, i am getting those triggers only when the class gets modified by the Java client running on Machine-2 (i.e. same client)

This is my code

```java
graph = new OrientGraph(connectionString, "root", "hello");
ODatabaseDocumentTx docDBRef = graph.getRawGraph();
docDBRef.begin();
try
{

docDBRef.registerHook(new ODocumentHookAbstract() {
-------
-------
});
docDBRef.commit();
}catch (Exception e) {
    docDBRef.rollback();
}
```

Is there any way, i can write a client which can get notified on any change in the database ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: BTW, i tried server side trigger and that works as expected. I mean, irrespective of any client modifying a record, the trigger gets fired. However, i am not able to get such triggers on a Java client. Java client receives triggers only when the same client modifies a record :( Any body tried such thing ? or is server side trigger the only option ??